# Paypal using credit card error

Tags: php, paypal

After people pay in our site using paypal they are sent to an address http://www.xyxyxy.com/xyxyx.php where they can access the service we are selling them. The problem is this... when they pay with paypal, the system is working perfectly, but, when they pay with a credit card, they are sent to a page that says... Permission to download denied....

What can I do? Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the paypal IPN handler in your code. It probably sets some variables that the credit card path doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pay yourself with a credit card, then you can see exactly what goes wrong. Or ask a friend for a favour. With the goal of seeing for yourself what goes wrong.

Failing that, try to get the url of the page that gives this error message from the people who are experiencing it.